# How to find coordinates of mouse cursor in interface builder

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, coordinates

I want to know exactly where I am placing my images programatically, and therefore need to know the coordinates of my storyboard.

Is there a way to view these from the interface builder in Xcode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your workspace dimension is 320X460 suppose you want to add a button programmatically first go into IB and place a button where you want it to be and then in the right side check the coordinates of button in show the size inspector and use those coordinates in your code this will give you a fair idea about where your button will go after you add it programmatically... hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

NO. Use your imagination. Programmatically added visual objects cannot be seen in IB.

Instead, you could place an object in IB, adjust it's position to the desired one, read it's frame, delete it from IB, and use it's frame values to programmatically add id.

Comment: I know we can not see objects in IB, but if I had known the coordinates of it I could get great guidance by moving my mouse cursor around the IB, wouldn't I?